# only shows php and not the other languages in netbeans 6.9?

Tags: netbeans

i have installed the latest netbeans 6.9 rc2 for all languages, but i only see the php tab when i use it.

prior to this version i had 6.9 beta for only php, but i have deleted that folder.

maybe the settings are still there, so it only shows php?

how can i clean everything so that it shows all other languages?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check and see which plugins are installed in Netbeans in Tools > Plugins.
They might be installed, but not enabled.

If you really get stuck you might still have the old netbeans user directory, with just the PHP plugins installed as your userdir.
You can delete this directory to get a clean install of netbeans. 
On linux you will find it in; ~/.netbeans/6.9rc2/ (version number might be different), on windows it will in your C:\Users\ or C:\Documents & Settings\ depending on your version. OSX i dont know, guess similar to linux.

Comment: i deleted the folders from my user dir, and then i installed a new version of 6.9. they were installed as u said not activated. i had to create a new project for it to enable that project's language. they have changed it i guess, before they were all activated by default.